# How to make a cross-domain form CSRF and replay resistant?

Tags: html, json, cross-domain, csrf

I'm contemplating making a project, but I'm wondering if cross-site request forgery would make it impossible to secure.

Basically, I want to have a web service that generates a form using the usual tricks(JSON-P and iframes) on another domain's page. So WebService.example.com generates a form's HTML, and it's shown to the user on User.example.com

This form, I assume will have to use the injected iframe trick to submit the form from javascript. Because anyone would be able to just get the same data from WebService.example.com, how can I ensure that it's actually only coming from User.example.com? Preferably, without having to have any server-side code running on User.example.com.

Note, I'll be using ASP.Net for the WebService, but I'd like it explained in a language/framework agnostic manner

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty hard to do without using server side scripts on both domains.

If you change your architecture and just use Cross-Domain Messaging (host the form etc in the top domain, use iframe for communication) then you could use the XDM to verify that it is indeed the intended domain you are talking to.

If you only target HTML5-capable browsers then use `postMessage`, if you want broader support, and things like RPC etc then use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net), which abstracts all of the hassle with cross-domain messaging.

Actually, you can host your form in either document, you just need to use the XDM-communication in order to do a successful 'handshake', verifying the `origin`.